# how to get SUM of value from the collection?

Tags: magento2.4

I'm trying to get some of the values from the collection,
below is my code.

```
<?php 
public function RentalPartnerRevenue()
  { 
    $filter = $this->request->getParam('filter'); 
    $operator_id = $this->request->getParam('operator_id');   
    try{ 

        $completecollection1 = $this->_orderCollectionFactory->create()
                                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*');  
            
        if(isset($filter) && $filter  == 'totalrevenue'){
            //$completecollection1->addAttributeToSelect('grand_total')->getColumnValues('grand_total');       
            $completecollection1->getSelect()->joinLeft(
                'rider_detail as wrd',
                'wrd.booking_id = main_table.entity_id',
                ['entity_id','order_total', 'operator_id']
            )->order('wrd.created_at DESC')
             ->where('booking_status ="' . self::COMPLETED . '"')
             ->where('operator_id ="' . $operator_id . '"');

            echo $completecollection1->getSelect()->__toString();
            //print_r($completecollection1->getData());

        }elseif(isset($filter) && $filter  == 'todaysrevenue'){ 

        }elseif(isset($filter) && $filter  == 'lastmonthrevenue'){ 

        }elseif(isset($filter) && $filter  == 'lastthreemonthrevenue'){ 

        }elseif(isset($filter) && $filter  == 'selectcustomdate'){

        }
         
        if(count($completecollection1->getData())){   
           $PartnerArray = [];
            foreach ($completecollection1 as $Partnerrevenue) {  
             if(isset($PartnerArray[$Partnerrevenue->getData('operator_id')])){ 
                 $PartnerArray[$Partnerrevenue->getData('operator_id')] = $PartnerArray[$Partnerrevenue->getData('operator_id')] + $Partnerrevenue->getData('grand_total');                 
               }else{
                 $PartnerArray[$Partnerrevenue->getData('operator_id')] = $Partnerrevenue->getData('grand_total');
               } print_r($PartnerArray); // right data
            } 
            
        }
    }catch (Exception $e) {
        return $this->setResponse(500, $e->getMessage(), null);
    }
  }
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
[2707173] => 700.0000
)
Array
(
[2707173] => 7500
)
Array
(
[2707173] => 12900
)
Array
(
[2707173] => 18300
)
Array
(
[2707173] => 23700
)
Array
(
[2707173] => 25500
)
Array
(
[2707173] => 35500
)
Array
(
[2707173] => 45500
)
Array
(
[2707173] => 79500
)
Array
(
[2707173] => 113500
)
```

here **2707173** is operator_id
and => 700.000 to 113500 is **order_total**

now I want to get **sum of order_total**, but I don't know how can I sum these values.
please help me with this.

thanks.

Comment: You mean you want to sum of array value? inside foreach?

Comment: @RohanHapani Yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my understanding of your requirement I am sharing the below code check if this helps, This will sum up all the values based on the operator id.

```
if(count($completecollection1->getData())){
    $PartnerArray = [];
    foreach ($completecollection1 as $Partnerrevenue) {
        $PartnerArray[$Partnerrevenue->getData('operator_id')][] = $Partnerrevenue->getData('grand_total');
    }
    $orderTotal = [];
    foreach($PartnerArray as $operatorId => $data) {
        $orderTotal[$operatorId] = array_sum($data);
    }
   return $orderTotal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Magento allow us to retrieve all value of a specific column via `$collection->getColumnValues('column');`, in your case we can get the sum of grand total as per following:

```
$sumOfTotal = array_sum($completecollection1->getColumnValues('grand_total'));
```